# When to use abstraction and when an interface?

Tags: java

I vaguely understand the difference between abstraction and interfaces, but what I can't understand at all, is when to use abstraction and when an interface. What are the variables needed for me to choose abstraction over interfaces and vice versa? Most of the answers online are for showing the differences, but even though I understand them. I don't know when one is more appropriate.

Comment: I presume you mean "abstract classes" rather than "abstraction". Abstraction is a concept. Both abstract classes and interfaces are ways of achieving abstraction.

Comment: In general: prefer to use an interface if it's possible. You will eventually encounter a situation where an interface is not possible, and you'll have to use an abstract class instead (for example, if you need to store data in it).

Comment: [Prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general age-old principle is: Stick with interfaces until you're forced to write an abstract class.

An `interface` in Java is a non-instantiable type which defines a public interface that other types can *choose* to conform to.

- Interfaces can declare public methods, which must be defined by their implementors. All such methods are implicitly `abstract`, so you don't need to use the word `abstract`.
- In old versions of Java, interfaces could not have default implementations, so *every* method was `abstract`. This is no longer the case, and interfaces can now have default implementations that get used in `implement`ing classes unless replaced.
- In recent versions of Java, interfaces can declare `private` helper methods. These can help in implementing default implementations.
- Interfaces can never have constructors or instance variables.
- A class can `implement` several interfaces.

An `abstract class` is just a class that cannot be instantiated. Abstract classes are not required to  define any `abstract` methods, though you'll usually want to.

- Abstract classes can declare methods with any visibility: `public`, `private`, `protected`, and package-private.
- Abstract classes can implement methods or leave them `abstract`. Methods in an abstract class are *not* implicitly `abstract` and must be marked as such.
- An abstract class can have constructors, which must be called by `extend`ing classes in their own constructor using `super`. An abstract class can have instance variables of any visibility, and these work just like instance variables in any parent class.
- A class can only `extend` one class, either an `abstract` one or a concrete one. A class' `abstract`ness does not change the number of superclasses it's allowed to have.

`abstract class`es should be the exception and not the norm. You should use an abstract class if you need to maintain some internal state while also letting subclasses define your own behavior. A great example of this comes from the Java Swing GUI library: [`AbstractButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html). `AbstractButton` is the abstract parent of things that behave vaguely like buttons in a window, including buttons, toggle buttons, and items in a menu. Anyone can subclass `AbstractButton` and implement its members to define a button-like display. But `AbstractButton` also has to maintain a lot of internal state (much of it coming from `JComponent`) in order to communicate with the window and with the Swing API as a whole.

If you want to define the public interface for a collection of types, use an `interface`. If you want to provide default implementations for some of those methods and are using a version of Java released after 2014, use interfaces. If you need default implementations but are stuck in the 2000s, use an abstract class. Regardless of Java version, if you need private state such as instance variables or custom initialization like a constructor, use an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces:

Say you have an interface, like:

```
interface Animal {
  String makeNoise();
}
```

and a couple of classes that implement Animal:

```
class Cat implements Animal {
    String makeNoise() {
        return "Meow";
    }
}

class Dog implements Animal {
    String makeNoise() {
        return "Woof";
    }
}
```

Now you can use the interface as the return type, so a method can return a `Cat` or a `Dog`.

```
String makeAnimalMakeNoise(int animalId) {
    Animal animal = pretendAnimalService.getDogOrCat(animalId);

    animal.makeNoise();
}
```

Abstract Classes:

Let's say you have an abstract class:

```java
abstract class Animal {
    public String makeNoise() {
        return "Whistle";
    }

    abstract public String getName();
}
```

Now, any class that extends this would need to implement the `getName` method:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    String getName() {
        return "Pussy";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    String getName() {
        return "Fido";
    }
}
```

Both of the above classes implemented the required `getName` method, but they also have access to the parent classes `makeNoise` method, which can also be overridden if required.

It's important to note the other differences too, which are:

- You can only extend one abstract class but you may implement multiple
  interfaces.
- Interfaces should be used when different types should have the same method signature whereas abstract classes should be used when implementations share a common behaviour.
- They are not mutually exclusive.
- An interface can only have public methods where as abstract classes can have public and protected methods.

Comment: Note that since Java 9, interfaces can have default method implementations, as well as private methods. The linked article is out of date.